# How do I make a server that will backup computers over the internet?

Tags: hardware, files, backup

I need to know how to make a Ubuntu server that will backup ALL the files on about 4 computers that are both PC and MAC, I have the proper hardware, but I don't know where to start with the backup system. Any ideas or help?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [BackupPC](http://sourceforge.net/projects/backuppc/).

> BackupPC is a high-performance, enterprise-grade backup system for
>   backing up Linux, WinXX PCs, Macs and laptops to a server's disk.
>   Features include clever pooling of identical files, no client-side
>   software, and a powerful Apache/CGI user interface.

Also you might want to consider doing [rsync](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/rsync) over SSH.

Another option is using [Bacula](http://www.bacula.org/en/)

> Bacula is a set of Open Source, computer programs that permit you (or
>   the system administrator) to manage backup, recovery, and verification
>   of computer data across a network of computers of different kinds.
>   Bacula is relatively easy to use and efficient, while offering many
>   advanced storage management features that make it easy to find and
>   recover lost or damaged files. In technical terms, it is an Open
>   Source, network based backup program.

Helpful reading [Turn an Old Computer into a Networked Backup, Machine with Ubuntu](http://lifehacker.com/5919558/turn-an-old-computer-into-a-networked-backup-streaming-or-torrenting-machine-with-ubuntu)

<sup>Sources:Sourceforge & Bacula</sup>